# XPATH return with no child tag and child tags of specific value

Tags: xml, xpath

New to XPATH, I have the following xml:

```
<lessons>
    <lesson>blah</lesson>
    <lesson>blah</lesson>
    <lesson>blah</lesson>
    <lesson>
        <A>Yes</A>
    </lesson>
    <lesson>
        <A>No</A>
    </lesson>
    <lesson>
        <A>Booyah</A>
    </lesson>
    <lesson>
        <A>Wowzer</A>
    </lesson>
</lessons>
```

What I want is to select lessons with no `<A>` Tag, and only lessons with `<A>` tag having text Yes.  Others to be excluded.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the description of your requirement reads "Return all X, but excluding all that have Y", you almost always need a *predicate*.

Simply use the following XPath expression:

```
/lessons/lesson[not(A = 'No')]
```

Assuming a well-formed input document (yours is not, because one of the `lesson` elements is not properly closed), the result will be (individual results separated by `--------`):

```
<lesson>blah</lesson>
-----------------------
<lesson>blah</lesson>
-----------------------
<lesson>blah</lesson>
-----------------------
<lesson>
<A>Yes</A>
</lesson>
-----------------------
<lesson>
<A>Booyah</A>
</lesson>
-----------------------
<lesson>
<A>Wowzer</A>
</lesson>
```

---

> cause i want specifically Yes, and exclude anything else that could be in  be it No or any other value

Then use

```
/lessons/lesson[A = 'Yes']
```

and the result will be (obviously):

```
<lesson>
  <A>Yes</A>
</lesson>
```

---

If you meant to also select `lesson` elements if they do not have an `A` child element at all, use

```
/lessons/lesson[A = 'Yes' or not(A)]
```

and the result will be

```
<lesson>blah</lesson>
-----------------------
<lesson>blah</lesson>
-----------------------
<lesson>blah</lesson>
-----------------------
<lesson>
<A>Yes</A>
</lesson>
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias, I actually edited post, just excluding no won't work cause i want specifically Yes, and exclude anything else that could be in <A> be it No or any other value.

Comment: @jensanity5000 See my edit - pick the one that suits your requirement.

Comment: thanks again.  That will only bring back the one less with <A> of yes.  However I want that and the other "blank" lessons.  So I want the three first lessons and the <A> yes lesson, excluding the rest. Sorry if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @jensanity5000 I already added a path expression for that case.

Comment: Yes but that will only not give me 'No" I also don't want Wowzer, or Booyah in that list.  I actually don't know what other values could be there in this case, I just know I want base lessons with no <A> tag and those with <A> tag yes.  anything else needs to be discarded.

Comment: @jensanity5000 That's exactly what my last suggestion returns - please look at my answer before commenting again.

Comment: Yes perfect.  That last one you posted was what I was trying to get at!